# how make product name invisible when checkbox is true in other module?

Tags: odoo, invoice

I want to make that when I click true in (other)checkbox in the invoice,the (product) do not dispaly ( be invisible) in the invoice line and when I click false in the checkbox the product display
fields in the picture:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Hiding based on other module field you can use
 ** attrs="{'invisible': [('your_other_module_field','condition','value')]}"**

```
<field name="your_field_to_hide" attrs="{'invisible': [('your_other_module_field','condition','value')]}"/>
```

But in this case You can not hide column. you have to use invisible="1"

Comment: <field name = "product_id" position = "attributes">
                        <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': [('test_id','=',True)]}</attribute>

Comment: Try this <field name = "product_id" position = "attributes"> <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': [('parent.test_id','=',True)]}</attribute>

Comment: Uncaught Error: the field parent.test_id is not in domain [["parent.test_id","=",true]]

Comment: which version are you using ?
this  <field name = "product_id" position = "attributes"> <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': [('parent.test_id','=',True)]}</attribute>  is working in version 11

Comment: I am use version 10